# glReadPixels() fails, but replacing GL_RGBA with GL_RGB makes it work, inside pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, xorg, glreadpixels

On Ubuntu 14.04, I'm testing an open source project which uses pyglet.
I'm running `/usr/bin/Xorg` directly and separately, using the Nvidia driver with a Nvidia GPU.

The project has [this part](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py#L93):

```
buffer = pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer()
image_data = buffer.get_image_data()
```

And `pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: invalid operation` occurs when it executes the second line.

Therefore I debugged using `PYGLET_DEBUG_GL_*` environment variables, and figured out that the error happens while calling `glReadPixels(0, 0, 600, 400, 6407, 5121, <pyglet.image.c_ubyt)`.

The pyglet part of the stack trace is here: [1](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/src/pyglet-1.2.4/pyglet/image/__init__.py#__init__.py-2090), [2](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/src/pyglet-1.2.4/pyglet/gl/lib.py#lib.py-104)

`ColorBufferImage` class originally uses `GL_RGBA`, and I tried changing it to use `GL_RGB`, by modifying the 2 lines [here](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/src/pyglet-1.2.4/pyglet/image/__init__.py#__init__.py-2110).

I didn't anticipate it, but `GL_RGB` made the `glReadPixels()` call work without the error, though I cannot use it since the open source project assumes it would be `GL_RGBA`.

I really want to know how to make `GL_RGBA` work...

Could someone please help me?

**Update**: I've just tried an another option, and I think changing the data type from `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` to `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` works (I also changed the buffer's primitive type from `GLubyte` to `GLushort`). If this is right, is this a bug of pyglet?

Comment: So does your buffer have alpha values?

Comment: @stark Thanks for commenting, yes the buffer is `(GLubyte * (len(self.format) * self.width * self.height))()` and `len(self.format)` is 4.

Comment: @noname; That does not answer the question. `self.format` is still ambiguous. What is `self.format`? Is the buffer you read into large enough? Does the type match the format?

Comment: @thokra It's just 'RGBA', and its length is 4. This representation is used inside pyglet.

Comment: @thokra ADD: I accidentally pressed Enter, so I'm adding. I think the buffer size is OK.

The original combination which doesn't work: `GL_RGBA`, `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GLubyte`

The new combination that works: `GL_RGBA`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, `GLushort`

So what I'm wondering is, I had to modify pyglet's source code, does that mean it's a bug?

Comment: Would this solve the problem? `buffer.get_image_data().get_data("RGBA", 4)` or `"RGB", 3`? Does it make a difference? If not is there another option than to use `get_buffer_manager` and it's subfunction?

Comment: Or fiddle around with the [Context Config](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/context.html) parameter that controls the `alpha_size` for instance.